# How to display add node form with node reference?

Tags: 6, forms, nodes

I have a very similar functionality to stackoverflow - i.e. I have a a view that display question and below it there are answers (seperate nodes references).

Currently, in order to add new answer to the question, the user has to click on a link, which takes him to add node form. But I need to display the form below the view, so the user can answer without being redirected to add node form on a seperate page. I guess it can be done programatically using `drupal_get_form()` function, but I have no idea how to start. Can anyone give me any suggestion or tutorial? Or maybe there is module for that..?  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, there's a module for that! http://drupal.org/project/formblock I believe this can work with node-references with a bit of configuration. If not, you can use this tutorial to populate the node reference: http://grayside.org/comment/830 which should get carried over by the FormBlock module.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following code to load an empty node creation form:

```
//create empty node and build node edit form
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $node = (object) array('uid' => $user->uid, 'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''), 'type' => 'player', 'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE, 'title' => ''); 
    $player_form = drupal_get_form('player_node_form', $node);
```

Comment: I tried to include it in the php footer, but it doesnt display anything. I've changed player to answer...